# Add variable to python dictionary with string operator

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Trying to add a string that contains a variable that could be anything to one of my dictionaries.Temp is just a random string of text, 33 chars long.

```
lst = ''
temp = ''
def randomstr():
    global lst, temp
    temp = ''
    lst = [random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in xrange(33)]
    temp = "".join(lst)
headers = {"Content-type": "text/xml", "Accept": "text/plain", "Host": "chat.site.com", "Accept-Encoding": "identity", "User-agent": "Client Python-urllib/2.6", "userid": "39",}
headers["If-none-match"] = "jrc-%s"%temp
headers["If-none-match"] = "jrc-" + temp
headers["If-none-match"] = "jrc-%s" % (temp)
```

None of these work, what am i doing wrong?

```
print temp
print headers
```

output:

K60IcFrZveioTrPY9cAJ38IOANj67eElK

{'Accept-Encoding': 'identity', 'Host': 'chat.site.com', 'Accept': 'text/plain',
 'User-agent': 'Client Python-urllib/2.6', 'userid': '39', 'If-n
one-match': 'jrc-', 'Content-type': 'text/xml'}

its weird because temp outputs fine on its own but not in the dict

```
headers["If-none-match"] = "jrc-"+str(temp)
```

also does not output

Comment: I changed a double quote to a single quote.  I assume it was just a typo ?

Comment: What do you mean by "dont work"? Be specific about the problem.

Comment: What's the value of temp? How can we be sure it's not an empty string for example?

Comment: Since you didn't say what exactly isn't working, and the syntax looks fine, and the dictionary is called `headers` - is it possible that `temp` has some unsafe characters? HTTP headers are limited to the ASCII range - does `temp` have some Unicode characters or line-breaks?

Answer (score 0):

In the case where `temp` is a `tuple` with more than one element, the above will fail:

```
 "jrc-%s"%temp #not the right number of elements for formatting
 "jrc-"+temp   #can't concatenate string and tuple
```

I believe it will also fail if `work` is a `dict` for similar reasons.

Something which should "work"* is `"jrc-"+str(temp)`

*work here is defined by not throwing an exception